# Keywords to make my Condition check correct in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I want a where condition in MS Access Query, 
but i am not able to get that correct.
Here is the c# representation of my condition

```
If(vEmail==null)
 return false;
else
 return Email==vEmail
```

I want it to be translated into MS Access Query's where condition.

I dont know what are the keywords of MS Access query can be used here.

Answer (score 2):

`IIF(IsNull(vEmail), "False", vEmail) AS Email`

This should do the trick. It says:

If vEmail Is Null (IsNull would result in true), then return "False", else return `Email`.

`vEmail=Null` Shouldn't work, because Null != Null. There are also a couple other ways you can check for null.

- `IsNull`
- `Not IsNull`
- `YourField Is Null`
- `YourField Is Not Null`